# Dropdown add color to custom text

Tags: javascript

Im using a dropdown taken from db, and showing

Size 2 - Out Of Stock
Size 4 - Stock
Size 5 - Out Of Stock

How can i add red color to out of stock text and green color on stock text via js?

My Dropdown:

```
<select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                    <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                  </select>
```

Comment: Can you inspect element your drop-down? and post a screenshot or the code here?

Comment: more code more info...

Comment: This would be a job better suited to CSS (and probably PHP), not JavaScript. You'd need to use PHP to output a unique 'identifier' for the option that you want to make red, and then use either JavaScript or CSS to target this identifier.

Comment: If you're asking for JS, you need to provide an attempt at JS (and eliminate the PHP, which won't be involved).

Comment: I have worked on this:
if (document.getElementById('attribute1012').options.text == 'Out Of Stock')
        {
            alert("Test");
        }

And i would like to set this text to red...i dont know how to do this in js...need to do it via js .

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is actually rather difficult to do. According to the HTML specification, the **[`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)** tag can only contain text. That means that you can't add a `<span>` or something nice to only target the "In Stock" / "Out Of Stock" text.

Having said that, you **can** target the collection of `<option>` elements themselves, and the easiest way to control the colours would be to assign each `<option>` a `class` while outputting them through PHP. Then you can target them with **[`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)**, loop over them and style the text colour through **[`.style.color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)**.

```js
var in_stock = document.getElementsByClassName('in_stock');
var out_of_stock = document.getElementsByClassName('out_of_stock');

for (var i = 0; i < in_stock.length; i++) {
  in_stock[i].style.color = 'green';
}

for (var i = 0; i < out_of_stock.length; i++) {
  out_of_stock[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option class="in_stock">Size 2 - In Stock</option>
  <option class="out_of_stock">Size 5 - Out Of Stock</option>
</select>
```

Note that setting the colour for the `<option>` elements does not set the **default** selection colour. For this, you'll want to target the `<option>` tag directly, which can be done with **[`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)**. You'll want to set the colour of this to the first `<option>` by default, and the **selected** option when the selection changes:

```js
var in_stock = document.getElementsByClassName('in_stock');
var out_of_stock = document.getElementsByClassName('out_of_stock');

for (var i = 0; i < in_stock.length; i++) {
  in_stock[i].style.color = 'green';
}

for (var i = 0; i < out_of_stock.length; i++) {
  out_of_stock[i].style.color = 'red';
}

/* Default <select> styling */
var the_select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
the_select.style.color = document.getElementsByTagName('option')[0].style.color;

/* Further <select> styling */
the_select.onchange = function() {
  the_select.style.color = the_select.options[the_select.selectedIndex].style.color;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option class="in_stock">Size 2 - In Stock</option>
  <option class="out_of_stock">Size 5 - Out Of Stock</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps!